# CentOS 7 fails to reboot my PC

Tags: centos, reboot

I have small Pegatron PC with Linux. When I was using Windows 7, reboot worked correctly. I migrated to CentOS, everything works except **#reboot**. Computer is never turned off, it simply stops responding and stop accessing HDD (turning power off on and finishes reboot, but I need this to happen naturally). How can I solve it? Tried **shutdown -r** and **systemctl reboot**, but they behave same way.

Comment: Does `systemctl reboot` work the same way for you?

Comment: @Haxiel, answered

Answer (score 0):

First install `acpid`

```
yum -y install acpid
systemctl start acpid
systemctl enable acpid
```

Then edit `/etc/default/grub` to include `acpi=force reboot=warm` in the end of the existing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`.

Rebuild grub config:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

Comment: this doesn't help, same behaviour